# Line break in table and multicolumn layout problem

Tags: tables

I have a small problem. I would like to rebuild the following table:

[image]

Until now I made the following code:

```
\begin{tabular}{lllllll}\toprule
\textbf{Factor} & \textbf{Effect} & \textbf{Percentage of Variation} & \textbf{Confidence Intervall} & \textbf{Effect} & \textbf{Percentage of Variation} & \textbf{Confidence Intervall} \\ \midrule

I & 26.55 & ~ & (16.35,36,74) & 0.03 & ~ & (-0.02,0.07) \\

 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

My problem now is the following:

- I cannot get "Percentage of Variation" etc. on two lines (line break).
- I don't know how to make the "Additive Model" und "Multiplicative Model".

I would really appreciate if somebody could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick view on using [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) for the layout, and [`makecell`](http://ctan.org/pkg/makecell) for per-cell alignment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lrcrrcr}
  \toprule
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries Additive Model} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries Multiplicative Model} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}
  \textbf{Factor} & Effect & \makecell[cb]{Percentage \\ of Variation} & \makecell[cb]{Confidence \\ Interval} & 
    Effect & \makecell[cb]{Percentage \\ of Variation} & \makecell[cb]{Confidence \\ Interval} \\
  \midrule
  I   &  $26.55$ &      ~ & $( 16.35, 36.74)$ & $ 0.03$ &      ~ & $(-0.02, 0.07)$\rlap{\textsuperscript{a}} \\
  A   & $-26.04$ & $30.1$ & $(-36.23,-15.84)$ & $-0.97$ & $49.9$ & $(-1.02,-0.93)$ \\
  B   & $-26.04$ & $30.1$ & $(-36.23,-15.84)$ & $-0.97$ & $49.9$ & $(-1.02,-0.93)$ \\
  AB  & $ 25.54$ & $29.0$ & $( 15.35, 35.74)$ & $ 0.03$ & $\phantom{0}0.0$ & $(-0.02, 0.07)$\rlap{\textsuperscript{a}} \\
  $e$ &        ~ & $10.8$ &                 ~ &       ~ & $\phantom{0}0.2$ &               ~ \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

For small tables, manual `\phantom` adjustments are easy to make. Alternatively, one could consider [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) column specifications.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
  #1
  \end{tabular}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{*{7}{c}}\toprule
   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Additive model} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Multiplicative model}\\\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}
\textbf{Factor} & \textbf{Effect} & \head{\textbf{Percentage}\\ \textbf{of Variation}} & \head{\textbf{Confidence}\\ \textbf{Intervall}}& \textbf{Effect} & \head{\textbf{Percentage}\\ \textbf{of Variation}} & \head{\textbf{Confidence}\\ \textbf{Intervall}} \\ \midrule

I & 26.55 & ~ & (16.35,36,74) & 0.03 & ~ & (-0.02,0.07) \\

 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, also using `makecell`, `siunitx`, `caption` and `threeparttable`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier, heuristica}
    \usepackage{array, booktabs,  caption}
    \def\cmidrulewidth{\lightrulewidth}
\captionsetup{font = bf, labelfont =sc, labelsep = quad}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{table-format=2.1}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadalign{cb}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Percentage of Variation Explained by the Two Models}
\begin{tabular}{ >{\boldmath}cS[table-format=-2.2]SccS[table-format=-1.2]Sc}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{Additive Model}}   & &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{Multiplicative Model}}  \\
 \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){6-8}
\thead{Factor} & {\thead{Effect}} & {\thead{Percentage\\ of Variation}} & \thead{Confidence\\ Interval} & &  {\thead{Effect}} & {\thead{Percentage\\ of Variation}} & \thead{Confidence\\ Interval} \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-8}\addlinespace
$ I $ & 26.55 & ~ &$  (16.35,36.74) $ & &  0.03 & ~ & $ (-0.02,0.07) $ \\
$ A  $  & -26.04 & 30.1 & $  (-36.23,-15.84) $ & &  -0.97 & 49.9 & $ (-1.02,-0.93) $ \\
$ B  $  & -26.04 & 30.1 & $ (-36.23,-15.84) $ & &  -0.97 & 49.9 & $ (-1.02,-0.93) $ \\
$ AB $  &  25.54 & 29.0 & $ (15.35, 35.74) $ & &   0.03 & 0.0 & $ (-0.02, 0.07) $\rlap{\tnote{a}} \\
$ e $ &        ~ & 10.8 &                 ~ &       ~ & &  0.2 &               ~ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a]Not significant.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]